# Update multiple entities and return a ViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I’m confused on how to work with updating two entities while using a ViewModel. I’ve done some searching but I’m not coming up with anything that seems to help me understand this.

I have two entities Person and Address. I use a ViewModel to combine the two together in order to display them in my Edit.cshtml. At the top of my View I declare the ViewModel to be used.

Now, I get to the actual Edit portion. I’m assuming I would have to make an update to each entity and then create a new ViewModel to return to the View since the Veiw is expecting a ViewModel?

I’m also curious if there is a way to let the View know that the update was successful so I can display a message at the top of the View or if it would be better to just redirect to the Index View.

Is this a correct way of coding this or is there a more streamlined way to accomplish the same thing?

Top of my .cshtml page

```
@model Project.Models.MemberViewModel
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult MyAccount(MemberViewModel model)
    {
        if (model.PersonId == 0)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        MemberViewModel updatedVM = new MemberViewModel();
        using (var db = new DataContext())
        {
            Person currentPerson = db.Person.Find(model.PersonId);
            if (currentPerson == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            db.Entry(currentPerson).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();


            Address currentAddress = db.Address.Find(model.PersonId);
            if (currentAddress == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            db.Entry(currentAddress).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            ////update and return a ViewModel
            //updatedVM.FirstName = currentPerson.FirstName;
            //updatedVM.LastName = currentPerson.LastName;
            //updatedVM.Address = currentAddress.Address1;
            //updatedVM.City = currentAddress.City;
            //updatedVM.State = currentAddress.State;
            //updatedVM.Zip = currentAddress.Zip;
        }

        return View(updatedVM);
    }
```

Comment: You posting back just the `id` property of your model. Then your getting the `Person` and `Address` from the database, marking them as modified even though you have not modified anything and saving exactly the same objects back the the database (a bit pointless). You post method needs to be `public ActionResult MyAccount(MemberViewModel model)` then update the `Person` and `Address` objects based on the properties in your view model and once you have saved, redirect.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't tested out this code yet. I was just mocking up some stuff first.

Comment: Ok. So that makes more sense to me now. Creating a new viewModel and then updating it with the new values to pass back to the View is not necessary (which is what I kind of thought). I just pass back the ViewModel that was passed in except that I might add a new property to the view model to track if the update was successful. Something along the lines of UpdateStatus and if it =0 then don't display a message. Setting =1 I could display a success message and -1 could be a failure message.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best practice would be to redirect to Index.cshtml after successfully saving the data (I think this is the whole idea of keeping MVC clean):

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

I would only show an error message if there is trouble with the data.This can be done similar to this:
You can add these to the ViewModel:

```
bool hasErrors;
string errorMessage;
```

and in the view you would implement at the top of the page:

```
@if(Model.hasErrors)
{
<div>Model.errorMessage</div>
}
```

The idea is to validate the data inside the ViewModel constructor, or inside the controller, and if there is something wrong just set `hasErrors = true` and a custom `errorMessage` and show it in the view.cshtml.

Hope it helps.